# Extract links from html source

Tags: delphi

I have a problem I have no idea how I can extract multiple links from html source code

html code are in Memo1 and links are extracted to memo2 ..

I use this function to extract links between 2 tangs or between 2 strings.

```
Function ExtractBetweenTags(Const Line, TagI, TagF: string): string;
var
  i, f : integer;
begin
  result := '';
  i := Pos(TagI, Line);
  f := Pos(TagF, Copy(Line, i+length(TagI), MAXINT));
  if (i > 0) and (f > 0) then
    Result:= Copy(Line, i+length(TagI), f-1);
end;
```

This gives only 1 link ..
so how I can get all links I have tried many times but no luck :/

Comment: Look at the Delphi documentation for `PosEx`, which allows you to set a starting position for the next search.

Comment: Use an html parser  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @David Agree with you in general, but you provided link to question with huge history and it is hard to find anything usefull there :) I put link to one lib i know as answer.

Comment: Maybe this can help: [HTML Tag Parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348346/html-tag-parsing/14349613)

Answer (score 2):

An HTML parser is the only real solution for such task. You can find free one here:

http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/tidy/history

Comment: @beingbad It comes with demo projects, one of them DITidy_Extract_Links, did you tried to have a look at this demo?